# Is there any literature reference for types of judgement: analytic, synthetic and evaluative?

Tags: knowledge

I am trying to search for literature that describes the various types of judgements people make based on their content. Most of the well-known works like that of Kant talk about two types of judgements: analytic and synthetic. I found a resource (http://www.rbjones.com/rbjpub/philos/epistem/rbj019.htm) that talks about three kinds of judgements: analytic, synthetic and evaluative.

Is there some literature that gives me a good, complete understanding of the types of judgements based on content that I can cite in any of my own research?

Also, I'm not a philosopher, so if the references were succinct and easy to comprehend, that would be better :)

Comment: Have you come across the SEP's [entry on Kant's theory of Judgment](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/kant-judgment/)?

Comment: Yes, I've glanced through it. It talks about analytic vs synthetic and a priori vs a posteriori. There's no mention of "evaluative judgements" or evaluations. Is that a recognised, distinct type?

Comment: Evaluative judgments only come in later, in the *Critique of Judgment*, and are thus of a different order than the earlier judgments.  You say you are not a philosopher; what kind of paper are you working on?  This would help find the literature appropriate to your case.  (For example: are you dealing with aesthetic/artistic judgments, or political judgments, or phenomenological issues of how we determine a cup is blue?, etc.)

Comment: Thanks, I'll look that up. My focus is mainly in consumable, online resources like Wikipedia. When a person reads an article, he/she forms a reaction in his/her head (reaction/judgement/evaluation/...). I'm trying to systematically analyse what that contains.